# Is the Broken Sobolev Space is complete?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

The definition of broken Sobolev space is: Let $\Omega$ be the domain and $\mathcal{E}_h$ be the finite number of partitions of $\Omega$. For any real number $s \geq 0$, we denote the broken Sobolev space
\begin{equation}
H^s\left(\mathcal{E}_h\right)=\left\{\mathsf{u} \in L^2(\Omega): ~\text{for all}~ E \in \mathcal{E}_h,~\left.\mathsf{u}\right|_E \in H^s(E)\right\},
\end{equation}
equipped with the broken Sobolev norm:
\begin{equation}
\|\mathsf{u}\|\strut_{H^s\left(\mathcal{E}_h\right)}=\left(\sum_{E \in \mathcal{E}_h}\|\mathsf{u}\|\strut_{H^s(E)}^2\right)^{1/2}.
\end{equation}
Here, $\|\mathsf{u}\|\strut_{H^s(E)}^2$ is a Sobolev norm on an element E of the domain $\Omega$.

Please give some ideas with an explanation, how I can prove or disprove.

Comment: By "the finite number of partitions" do you mean "a partition of $\Omega$ in a finite number of open sets", or maybe something else entirely? Also I'm assuming the $I$ is supposed to be a $E$.

Comment: If the "*broken parts*" are regular enough (say Lipschitz) then I see no difference between $H^s(\mathcal{E}_h)$ and just the Cartesian product of the $H^s(E)$ for $E \in \mathcal{E}_h$. So it is complete.

Comment: @BrunoB  The domain $\Omega$ is bounded and we are discretizing domain into the finite elements and $\mathcal{E}_h$ be the collection of all that elements.  Yes, $I$ I wrote by mistake, now I have corrected it, thanks for that.

Comment: @cs89  There is a jump in between the elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "a jump"? Say $\Omega = (0,2)$ and $\mathcal{E}_h = \{ E_1, E_2 \}$ where $E_1 = (0,1)$ and $E_2 = (1,2)$. Take $u_1 \in H^s(E_1)$ and $u_2 \in H^s(E_2)$. Their concatenation belongs to $H^s(\mathcal{E}_h)$ as you define it. The fact that you may have $u_1(1) \neq u_2(1)$ does not matter much as you are only asking for $u \in L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: @cs89  understood..thanks for the clarification.